# Jbpm process state subprocess states

Tags: subprocess, jbpm

In JBPM I have a parent process with subprocess defined in it. I'm creating subprocess instances based on user input.Parent and subprocess has their own states(human tasks). Initially all are created with submitted state. I want to achieve below things

1. When user moves one of the subprocess state to pending (by completing submitted task) i want to move parent process to waiting state
2. when user completes all the tasks on all the subprocess then i want to move parent process state to complete

Currently my workflows looks like

**parent process**

[image: parent process]

**subprocess**

[image: subprocess]

As you can see in the images Initially parent process and subprocess are in waiting approval.

We have react API where user can approve or cancel a subprocess.
If user approves subprocess from ui..ui will call node application and node will call jbpm to approve or cancel subprocess.

When the user approves last subprocess, we are doing below two actions

1. from node we are approving last subprocess
2. from node approving parent process

when user cancels atleast one subprocess, we are doing below two actions

1. from node cancel that subprocess
2. from node cancel parent proces

But I want to achieve this automatically using jbpm flow and avoid second call in the both cases.

Is this can be achievable?
Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: share with us the bpmn and try to explain more you interest ..

Comment: I have updated with more description and images

Comment: This can be done as you can automatically query and modify task state and I believe you can execute from a given node.